# Change language for Google authentication request - Oauth 2.0

Tags: c#, google-api

I have this request for Google Oauth 2.0 authentication details:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&amp;scope={0}&amp;access_type=offline&amp;redirect_uri={1}&amp;pageId=none&amp;client_id={2}&amp;from_login=1&amp;as=3c65425ab09c7
```

How can I set the authentication page language to be the user Google account language?

Comment: Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

`lang=en` no longer seems to work.  However, **`hl=en`** does. It's important to note, that Google does not recommend the usage of that, since it is overwriting its logic in determining the best language. But, there could be cases for using it.

Comment: Thank you for this. Such a difficult thing to find.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the language prefix to your URI:

> lang=en

Comment: I want the language to be the google user account language, not english

Comment: That cannot be set because the user has not been logged in yet. When the user enters his ID and password and Google verifies it, only then the user preferences can be read and applied. Furthermore it will be applied by Google itself, we cannot set that language preference through coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?response_type=code&client_id=2222222222-hdaskjdhsakjdhsjadhksjadhhdjdkahdj.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fauth&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow&hl=zh-CN
```

SCROLL TO ***END***
See `&hl=zh-CN`

This will be Changeable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32623939)